# How to refer to conditional elements when unit testing React components using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a component which should show a login and subscribe button when a user is not authenticated, but should show a logout button when a user is authenticated.

How should I refer to these buttons when making the test?

All examples I found is people doing things like:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Button).lenght).toBe(1); // or whatever
```

But this obviously doesn't fit my case, since I always have at least one button and they are all the same, except for its text and action.

So I think I need some way to refer to these buttons, so I could pass an authenticated prop and check if exactly the logout button is rendered.

What would be the best approach on doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options for selecting elements can be seen in the documentation for [`Selector`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/selector.md).

In this case, you'd probably want to add css classes and use the class syntax, or perhaps the attribute syntax if your buttons use `input` elements where the text is set as an attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine what differentiates each button. First, find the button:

```
const button = wrapper.find(Button)
```

Then `expect()` on some characteristic of the button. For example,

```
expect(button.props().children).toEqual('Subscribe')
```

or

```
expect(button.props().children).toEqual('Logout')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use filter:

```
wrraper.find(Button).filter({className:'any'})
```

```
wrraper.find(Button).filter({label:'any'})
```

...etc